# TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

Tags: python

I am trying to apply `strptime` to a pandas series like the following :

```
    df['inward_date'] = datetime.strptime(df['inward_date'][:10], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

but it gives the above stated error. I can apply the loop and change it one by one but what is the more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply this conversion operation for every row item of your DataFrame, therefore use `df.apply` function e.g. to create a new `pd.Series` object and then assign it to the needed column.

```
df['inward_date'] = df['inward_date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[:10], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a simple conversion method:

```
import pandas as pd
# convert the 'Date' column to datetime format
df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```